# How can agentive language influence human behavior?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The effectiveness of agentive language on the perception of blame and punishment

Comment: Please give the source of that sentence. Or new information. And maybe you should read the help section for this site.

Comment: First, this is not even a sentence so interpreting its meaning is difficult. Second, "agentive" looks like a technical term in some field, in which case starting with the definition used in that field is essential. Third, the quoted material appears to be the title of an article, in which case the article itself may offer clues on what the title means.